# Can I use home.ejs instead of index.html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

The problem is, that when I'm deploying my website with FileZilla, I get a 403 forbidden. After a bit of searching for answers, it seems like it's because I don't have an index.html, but I'm using home.ejs instead. Can I set up my project, so it uses the home.ejs instead of an index.html?

I've made a one page website (which is going to be expanded to more pages), that works as a resume and I now need to deploy it to my domain. 
It is the 2nd version of my website, as I've been making it alongside a web development course I've been taking. The first version was made from html, css and Bootstrap, as a static page. The new version includes JavaScript, node.js, express and ejs.

My file structure looks like this

1. Project:

   1. node_modules
   2. public

      1. css
      2. images
   3. views:

      1. partials

         1. header.ejs
         2. footer.ejs
      2. home.ejs
   4. app.js
   5. package-lock.json
   6. package.json

Everything works when I deploy it locally (localhost:3000). I am pretty new to the whole web development thing. Even though the course I took was really good, it didn't talk about deploying a website to your own domain name.

Here is the app.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;
var $ = require("jquery")(window);

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home", {years: years, comp: comp, placing: placing});
});

app.listen("3000", function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

EDIT:
I needed a webserver to install node.js on.

Comment: Please share the code that exposes the route for "home.ejs" (or your complete app.js) with us. Otherwise we can only guess what the problem is.

Comment: FileZilla wont start nodejs, include a note in your question regarding how you run the script. If your getting 403 forbidden thats from your reverse proxy? Not using one?.. to me it sounds like your running apache, or ploped this code on a php host thinking it will work

Comment: To run a Node.js-based app on a web host, you'll need to make sure the host directly offers support for it. Check their documentation. Supporting hosts often require your app to accept and use inputs for specific settings, such as providing a PORT environment variable to replace your choice of `3000`. For other hosts, many only offer simple, shared hosting that's often based on Apache, Nginx, or a similar HTTP Server Applications. Those applications, by default at least, compete with Node.js rather than automatically integrating with it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, What do you mean by, how i run the script?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, by web-host, do you mean the Domain.com, who i got the domain name from?